# How do I translate this code from C to MIPS?

Tags: c, mips

This is the the original code we are given.  We need to translate the following C code into MIPS.

```
## int get_singleton(int value) {
##   for (int i = 0 ; i < GRID_SQUARED ; ++ i) {
##   if (value == (1<<i)) {
##      return i;
##   }
##   }
##   return 0;
## }
get_singleton:
    jr  $ra
```

So far I have this for my translation but I keep getting stuck in an infinite loop.

```
main:
    li  $a0, 0x010
    jal get_singleton

get_singleton:
    li  $v0, 0          # i
    li  $t1, 1
gs_loop:sll $t2, $t1, $v0       # (1<<i)
    beq $t2, $a0, get_singleton_done
    add $v0, $v0, 1
    blt $v0, 9, gs_loop     # repeat if (i < 9)
get_singleton_done:
    jr  $ra
```

Comment: you can use a compiler

Comment: @user3528438 Manually compiling C is a common exercise when learning assembly.

Comment: What were you expecting to happen after `get_singleton` returns?  (hint: what is the very next instruction after `jal get_singleton`?)

Comment: Its suppose to return the index of the first occurrence of a set bit in the number specified in the main function. Only if the number is a singleton meaning it only has one set bit will it return the index.